# Changing upper limit of the ckanapi to return all rows of data?

Tags: python, dataframe, ckan

I want to get all rows of the data from ckanapi:

https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi/blob/master/README.md#remoteckan
https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi

```py
demo = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN('https://www.govdata.de/ckan')
meta_original = demo.action.package_search(rows = 1000)
```

the upper limit is 1000, is there anyway to change that easily.
I've read the documentation

and this:

[Returning all Data from a CKAN API Request? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892890/returning-all-data-from-a-ckan-api-request-python)

still could not figure it out how to do it.

I have tried to add the limit but it does not work. I also tried to add the result by offset of 1000 but it does not work.